# MySql SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col_name IN (any value)

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am dynamically generating a python tuple

```
x = (1, 3)
```

So I can use MySql query in python like below,

```
f"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col_name IN {x}"
```

and it worked without problem.

But when I use empty tuple as x ( `x = ()`), I want the query to return all values of the table (just ignore the condition)

I know that I can use a if in python and pass the filter to sql only if x is not null.
But I want to use this in sql so it will be easier because the actual query string is so long and has the same problem in many places.

So my question is,

**IS THERE A WAY IN MYSQL LIKE BELOW,**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col_name IN (%)
```

just like we use

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col_name LIKE "%"
```

Comment: Why not just build your query in pieces? have a loop that goes over all such conditions and adds the proper string according to the tuple, I don't think you would find any SQL hacks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sql_escape(s, replace_all=False):
if replace_all:
    s = s.replace("_", "\\_").replace("%", "\\%")
return s.replace("\\", "\\\\") \
    .replace("\'", "\\\'") \
    .replace("\"", "\\\"")
def sql_in(col, values, default="TRUE"):
    if values is None:
        return default
    values = set(values) - {""}
    if len(values):
        values = ",".join("\'" + sql_escape(str(v).strip()).replace("%", "\\%").replace("_", "\\_") + "\'"
                          for v in values)
        return f"{col} IN ({values})"
    else:
        return default
```

Answer (score 2):

Came up with this python way. define a function like so:

```
def queryfriendly(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return f'"{value}"'
    return str(value)

def tuple_to_condition(col_name, tup):
    if len(tup):
        return f'{col_name} IN (' + ', '.join(list(map(queryfriendly, tup))) + ')'
    return 'TRUE'
```

Now in your query strings do this:

```
f"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE {tuple_to_condition('col_name', x)}"
```

The function just returns 'TRUE' so that the **WHERE** won't throw an error.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it . THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE ANSWER.  This is 100% working now.

Comment: Although this might break for strings. Ah the issues when you build SQL from strings dynamically. I would recommend to just look into a library like SQLAlchemy to do all this stuff simply.

Comment: @KavinduPasanKavithilaka just edited so it would also work for strings, note there are various datatypes (dates for instance) where this may not work you would need to add more stuff to the `queryfriendly` function. Not mentioning that we are not sanitizing the inputs here! being very dangerous (possibility of SQL Injection) would recommend using some library like above suggestion of SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score -2):

After trying out some codes, I found this as the answer.

```
x = [value1, value 2] # a list,, not a tuple
x.append("some value that does not in table")
x = tuple(x)
```

So the tuple won't be null.
Now we can get a help from eshirvana's answer

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col_name IN {x} OR {len(x) > 1}
```

Comment: Hey just noticed tuples with only one element have a string representation like `(1,)` and that causes SQL to throw error, does it work for you?

Comment: Yeah, I just got the error and I'm working on it

Comment: Do check my answer for this issue, I changed it to resolve that.